# div rtl direction and see horizontal Scroll page in bottom of FF

Tags: css, right-to-left

I put this code in my css file for righ to left direction:

```
div,td,input,textarea,table,tr,ul,li{direction:rtl;}
```

this worked in IE9, Chrome But in FF I see horizontal Scroll page in bottom .(NOTE: when i remove this code not show scroll page and worked) how to fix this for FF?!

Screen :
[image]

Comment: Do you have some plugin's that takes some of the right/left space?

Comment: @silagy: no, i dont have!

Comment: Use something like firebug and see what is on right end of screen. There must be some sort of element (maybe even hidden and not visible).

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context. Most likely you have something else on the page or in your Firefox browser that causes it. Can you try it on a different clean Firefox installation? In any case, why do you something so complicated to set a right-to-left direction? Unless you really know what you're doing, it's probably better to just do &lt;html dir="rtl">

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but you can try the following fix, It worked as a charm for me:

```
html {
     overflow-y: scroll;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}
```

Good luck.